# Bound of $\mathbb {P} \lbrace \vert X Y-\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y\vert >t \rbrace$ using Chernoff-Hoeffding inequality

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, inequality

From the Chernoff-Hoeffding inequality, we know that for $t \geq 0$ we have

$$\mathbb{P} \lbrace \vert X-\mathbb{E}X\vert >t\rbrace \leq 2 \exp\left(-\dfrac{t^{2}}{2}\mathbb{E}X\right).$$

What can I say about  $\mathbb{P} \lbrace \vert X Y-\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y\vert >t \rbrace$, is it possible to extend this result for this special case?

Is it true that 
$$\mathbb{P} \lbrace \vert X Y-\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y\vert >t \rbrace \leq \mathbb{P} \lbrace \vert X-\mathbb{E}X\vert >t \rbrace + \mathbb{P} \lbrace \vert Y-\mathbb{E}Y\vert >t \rbrace \leq 4 \exp\left(-\dfrac{t^{2}}{2}(\mathbb{E}X+\mathbb{E}Y) \right)$$ ?

Any help or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent ? If yes you can apply the inequality on $XY$. Could you recall the assumptions regarding Chernoff-Hoeffding ? Is there any extra assumptions concerning $X,Y$ ?